# как получить список из другого класса?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, класс

1 класс:

```
public static List<data_Users> GetDatafromdb(){
        //List<data_Users> listTemp;
         DatabaseReference myData;
         String USER_KEY="B";
        listTemp=new ArrayList<>();
        myData= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(USER_KEY);

        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(listTemp.size()>0)
                    listTemp.clear();
                // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
                for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    data_Users users2=ds.getValue(data_Users.class);
                    listTemp.add(users2);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
               // Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        };
        myData.addValueEventListener(postListener);
        return listTemp;
       // Intent intent_list;

       // intent_list = new Intent(Read_izm2.this, MainActivity.class);
       // intent_list.putExtra("firebase", (Serializable) listTemp);
       // return listTemp.get(0).name;
    }
```

2 класс:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout lr1;

    Intent intent_list;
    Intent intent_maps;
    Intent intent_dev;  //загрузка таблицы

    //firebase
    List<data_Users> listTemp;
    private DatabaseReference myData;
    private String USER_KEY="Bridge";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.e("error", "mostik");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //хочу реализовать интерфейс или что-то типо того, чтобы я вызвал класс и он вернул мне список
        listTemp=new ArrayList<>();
        Read_izm2 read_izm2= new Read_izm2();
        listTemp= read_izm2.GetDatafromdb();
       // listTemp=new ArrayList((Collection<? extends data_Users>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list_firebase"));

        Toast.makeText(this, "робит? = "+listTemp.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
```

как получить список из другого класса?
надо получить listTemp. Во 2 классе прочитать listTemp из 1 класса.

Comment: У вас точно класс? В первом коде

Comment: Ну неособо понимаю что там написано, но так как в первом коде статик метод,то во втором классе написать - (Название первого класса).GetDatafromdb(); 
А это рабочий код?

Comment: я просто не весь код скинул :). рабочий